# Data in pandas jumping to other cells

Tags: python, pandas, networking

I am trying to retrieve **show interface status** from network switches and putting into Pandas (I have other plans for future to use that data).

When I login to the network switch and run the cli command by myself, this the output I got

[image] Also table version of the switch outcome is below.

| Port | Name | Status | Vlan | Duplex | Speed | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fa0/1 | PC DATA | connected | 1 | a-full | a-100 | 10/100BaseTX |
| Fa0/2 | PC DATA | notconnect | 1 | auto | auto | 10/100BaseTX |
| Fa0/3 |  | disabled | 1 | auto | auto | 10/100BaseTX |
| Fa0/4 |  | connected | 1 | a-full | a-100 | 10/100BaseTX |
| Fa0/5 | KRONOS | notconnect | 1 | auto | auto | 10/100BaseTX |
| Fa0/6 | KRONOS | notconnect | 1 | auto | auto | 10/100BaseTX |

However, when use the command in python with netmiko and use the output as **Pandas Dataframe** I am having two issues. Output itself is fine but looks like cosmetic or table issue.

1. if name cell is empty in any row, all the other cells shifting to left. (for Example: Fa0/3 and Fa0/4)
2. if there is two or more words with spaces in name cell, each word is filling the cell right which is making data unusable.(For example: Fa0/1 and Fa0/2)

[image]

this is the output I am getting from my code.. Also I put that into tabular form below as you can see there are some discrepancies between two tables.

| Port | Name | Status | Vlan | Duplex | Speed | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fa0/1 | PC | DATA | connected | 1 | a-full | a-100 |
| Fa0/2 | PC | DATA | notconnect | 1 | auto | auto |
| Fa0/3 | disabled | 1 | auto | auto | 10/100BaseTX | nan |
| Fa0/4 | connected | 1 | a-full | a-100 | 10/100BaseTX | nan |
| Fa0/5 | KRONOS | notconnect | 1 | auto | auto | 10/100BaseTX |
| Fa0/6 | KRONOS | notconnect | 1 | auto | auto | 10/100BaseTX |

here is my code

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
import pandas as pd

def get_ip_address():
    ip_address_request = input("Please enter the IP address of the device: ")
    return ip_address_request

ip_address = get_ip_address()
switch = {
        "device_type":"cisco_ios",
        "ip": ip_address,
        'username': 'redacted',
        'password': 'redacted',        
}

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**switch)
prompt = net_connect.find_prompt()
hostname = prompt[:-1]
status = net_connect.send_command("Show interface status", use_textfsm=True)
net_connect.disconnect()

sum_status = []
lines = status.strip().split('\n')
headers = lines[0].split()

for line in lines[1:]:
    values = line.split()
    entry = {}
    for i, header in enumerate(headers):
        if i < len(values):
            entry[header] = values[i] 
    sum_status.append(entry)  


status_df = pd.DataFrame(sum_status)
status_df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
status_df.loc[:, 'Name'] = status_df['Name'].fillna('')
print(status_df.to_string(index=False))
```

Comment: Could you share a sample of what the input data looks like?

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover the first table above is the input data I am getting from Switch itself.

Comment: The key is to isolate the problem and provide a sample of the input dataframe and the desired output dataframe. Most people won't read your long code to answer your question.

Comment: @PandaKim
in my question, I put my input data in the first table.. I also put the output data as a result which I am getting. I explained the situation then I put my code.
how is it still not clear?

Comment: Your question is unclear. If your question is clear about SO Pandas, it can be solved within 15 minutes. This is because questions that do not have different answers are unclear. If you think you have explained enough, please provide the code to generate the input as a dataframe (use `pd.DataFrame`). Similarly, please provide the code to generate the desired output as `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: This will almost certainly need to be fixed at the raw data stage i.e. the output of the `net_connect.send_command` calls. Please [edit] your question and add the output from those calls (i.e. what is in `version`, `output` and `status`) to it.

Comment: I have simplified my code for better review. I also added images from actual Switch and from my code. 
I hope these changes makes my issue clearer for everyone. 
@Nick I removed **version** and **output** from calls.. the only important one is **status**

Comment: Cut & pasted text would be preferable to images, but looking at your data, I think `status_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(status), sep='\t+', engine='python')` would probably work

Comment: I have output data as a list. I dont have any csv to read which is creating Key error.

Comment: Your original output data is a string, you can put that into `read_csv` as I have suggested

Comment: If you replace your first image with the actual text output of the command, I'm sure a solution can be found.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do, really, with pandas. The problem is that there may be empty fields in the raw input. So this is incorrect:

```
for line in lines[1:]:
    values = line.split()  
    # generates bad input if there are empty fields
    # also generates bad input when a field contains a space
```

To fix this you have to parse or check the input (line by line) and determine whether or not there are empty fields/fields with spaces. For instance if "status" is always either "disabled" or "connected" then you could use that as anchor (to determine the column positions).

To verify that my comments are correct, you can add this:

```
headers = lines[0].split()
num_headers = len(headers)

for line in lines[1:]:
    values = line.split()
    assert len(values) == num_headers  
    # this raise an AssertionError for some lines
```

Looked at from the netmiko side, the problem is that you set the `use_textfsm=True` flag -- this is good and should have resulted in structured output, a list of dictionaries that could have been loaded directly into a pandas dataframe, without having to split or parse the lines -- but the actual output was a simple string. This apparently is caused by not having the proper ntc-template installed. For doc about this see:
https://pynet.twb-tech.com/blog/netmiko-and-textfsm.html